# IPP .Net SDK for Customer Account Data. Signed versions of assemblies required

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I'm working on COM-compatible .net assembly, based on IPP .Net SDK for CAD for using it in a SaaS application. My assembly needs to be strong-named. But it references Intuit.Ipp.DataAggregation.AggregationCategorizationServices.dll, Intuit.Ipp.DataAggregation.Core.dll and the other 8 assemplies, which are not strong-named.

Could you provide a signed versions of all the assemblies in SDK?

Thanks.

Comment: Please submit a support incident so we can follow up: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support/developer_support

Answer (score 0):

The .Net SDK 2.3.0 (for QBO v3) signed assemblies can be found here (direct link to .zip file):
https://intuitcorp.quickbase.com/up/bhvhx8wfg/g/r9/eg/va/IppDotNetSdkForQbApiV3-1.0.7-Signed.zip

Reference:
https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1204996-i-see-the-nuget-package-for-intuit-ipp-net-v2-3-where-do-i-get-signed-assemblies-for-the-same